# Unintentional Padding in Text Elements

Tags: html, css

I'm using tables per a client's request for a design. (Read: No other option)

All the table cells seem to be applying some sort of vertical padding and screwing up all my spacing.  I've changed the text/background color of one of the cells on the fiddle to show you what I mean.  I have tried setting margin and padding to 0 on all applicable elements.

Thanks for any help!

```
    <table width="346" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr height="66">
        <td width="85" style="padding:0;" align="left" valign="top">
            <span style="font-size:66px;font-weight:bold;line-height:50ox;">50</span>
        </td>
        <td width="50" align="left" valign="middle">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr height="30">
                    <td width="50" align="center" valign="bottom">
                        <span style="font-size:28px;font-weight:bold;">%</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr height="20">
                    <td width="50" align="center" valign="bottom">
                        <span style="font-size:28px;font-weight:bold;">OFF</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td width="211"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EMtxu/

(note that I'm only looking at the vertical padding, not the right side which is just a result of the cell size)

Comment: Did you start with a CSS reset? (I bet not)

Comment: you've made them a set width but not centered the text. add `text-align: center` to your td

Comment: @Diodeus Yes, but it happens with or without the reset.

Comment: @Prisoner No, I did that intentionally for spacing purposes.

Comment: The width of your `td` is a lot of it. It could be narrower. Changing the line-height of your span will position the text vertically more naturally. But otherwise, things are about right. In place of `50`, type `Bg`. You'll see the ascenders and descenders fill up the space. It looks padded on the bottom because your content has no descenders.

Comment: There is a typo in the first span's styles.  You have `line-height:50ox`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming the reason you are using inline styles is because you are doing an email. Try removing the `tr` heights on those child elements and set the line height for both `span`s. Here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EMtxu/2/

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're seeing is a combination of two things:

1. line-height. Your big "50" has a line-height associated with it that allows for ascenders/descenders (like the part of a lowercase "p" that descends below the baseline). In this case, that means extra space below the "50".
2. All TDs in a row are the same height, so the second TD adjusts to be as deep as the first TD, resulting in extra space there, too.

Solution: set a hard line-height on the "50" that is less than or equal to the font-size.